# Bulk operations in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, bulkinsert

So I have this array for my collection that I need to store using Bulk Operations:

```
let arr = [
    {
        name: "John",
        marks: 3
    },
    {
        name: "Mike",
        marks: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Andrew",
        marks: 6
    },
    {
        name: "John",
        marks: 8
    },
    {
        name: "John",
        marks: 4
    },
    {
        name: "John",
        marks: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Mike",
        marks: 1
    },
    {
        name: "Andew",
        marks: 3
    },
    {
        name: "Mike",
        marks: 6
    }
]
```

So what I am currently doing now is:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    if(Students.findOne({name: arr[i].name})){

        Students.update({name: arr[i].name}, {$inc: {marks: arr[i].marks]}});
    }
    else {

        Students.insert({name: arr[i].name, marks: arr[i].marks]});
    }
}
```

Now I have so many records in array which I have to add in Mongodb every minute.
So I need to perform this operation very fast.
How can I achieve this same behavior using Mongodb Bulk Operations?
So I have this array for my collection that I need to store using Bulk Operations:

```
let arr = [
    {
        name: "John",
        marks: 3
    },
    {
        name: "Mike",
        marks: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Andrew",
        marks: 6
    },
    {
        name: "John",
        marks: 8
    },
    {
        name: "John",
        marks: 4
    },
    {
        name: "John",
        marks: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Mike",
        marks: 1
    },
    {
        name: "Andew",
        marks: 3
    },
    {
        name: "Mike",
        marks: 6
    }
]
```

So what I am currently doing now is:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    if(Students.findOne({name: arr[i].name})){

        Students.update({name: arr[i].name}, {$inc: {marks: arr[i].marks]}});
    }
    else {

        Students.insert({name: arr[i].name, marks: arr[i].marks]});
    }
}
```

Now I have so many records in array which I have to add in Mongodb every minute.
So I need to perform this operation very fast.
How can I achieve this same behavior using Mongodb Bulk Operations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `upsert` in the `updateOne`query , so it will kind of look like:

```
Students.update(
  { name: arr[i].name },
  {
    {
      upsert: true
    }, {
      $set: data,
      $inc: {
        marks: arr[i].marks
      }
    }
  }
);
```

I would recommend to use `updateOne` if you don't want want the possibility to change multiple records

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/

Comment: Actually I need bulk writing for that, not simple  insertion and updation

Comment: @StormTrooper bulk is not a magic accelerator, it just pack operations in a single message on the wire, then mongo unpacks it and performs all writes one at a time. Using upsert you save on the `find` request which gives you much bigger gain in performance.

Comment: The reason of bulk insertion or updation is gain in performance, cz otherwise why would we need bulk operation?

Comment: @StormTrooper it's just evolution of the protocol. Bulk writes significantly reduce number of open connections and indeed speed up things dramatically, on heavy writes when primary has no free sockets left, or the client reaches out capacity of the connection pool.  "why do we need it if it doesn't help me" is not really an argument.  Upserts is there to solve exact your case. An attempt to use bulk writes in a loop of finds can cost you massive headache dealing with race conditions, unintended overwrites, and won't give you much gain in performance anyway.